# angular design a compare directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm planning to write a angular directive that will compare two objects (primitive type and object type).

My plan is:

- Write a `primitiveCompare` directive that compares primitive type and returns something like this:

  ```
  <primitiveCompare left="" right="" settings=""></primitiveCompare>
  ```
- Write a `objectCompare` directive that compares object type and returns something similar:

  ```
  <objectCompare left="" right="" settings=""></objectCompare>
  ```

Inside the `objectCompare` directive, I'm thinking to loop the object's keys and create a template dynamically, it would be something like:

```
Object.keys(left).forEach(function(key){
    if(typeOf key !== 'object'){
        html = html + '<primitiveCompare left='left[key]' right='right[key] settings=''> </primitiveCompare>
    else  html = html + '<primitiveObject left='left[key]' right='right[key] settings=''> </primitiveObject>
```

Would above design work well, or are there better solutions?

Comment: It could work, but you would have to use $compile service to make it work. Otherwise angular will not parse and compile your dynamically created html.

As for the design it smells extremely fishy. What are you trying to achieve here? Right now it does not look like useful directive to have and performance wise using directives to compare objects is very bad idea. Just imagine all that watches... Performance nightmare.

Comment: @sielakos   I was trying to write a directive that can show me the difference of comparing two object side by side (align the same/difference). In my head, I think the only thing I need is a result array that has all the information I need. Then I will just simply output to html to display.